# Invalid Document: Cannot encode object

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Sample documents in the collection are as follows:

```
[
   {  "_id" : ObjectId("57690ce4a89aa8aa92ed1896"),  "total_enters" : 308974,  "Segment" : "7",  "Chain" : "11625",  "Geography" : "303"},
   {  "_id" : ObjectId("57690ce4a89aa8aa92ed1897"),  "total_enters" : 311076,  "Segment" : "7",  "Chain" : "4624",  "Geography" : "303"}
]
```

I have a collection in the above format.

The following query is returning an error:
  `**InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: set(['$total_enters'])`

```
cursor_v2=db.Chain_share.aggregate([{
       "$group":{
        "_id":{"Geography":"$Geography","Segment":"$Segment"},
        "enters":{"$sum":"$total_enters"},
        "max_chain":{"$max":{"$total_enters"}}}
      }
    ])
```

The field `total_enters` is an aggregate field which was obtained as a result of `$sum` operation. Not able to figure out why it is not able to sum it up again?

What is causing the encoding error?

Comment: what is your pymongo and python version? The query works fine for me.

Comment: Pymongo v3.2 and Python 2.7

Comment: It works fine for me with Python 3.5.1, pymongo 3.2.2 and Mongo 3.2. Could you please execute this query in your mongo shell and check whether it works?